# extern "C" for functions loaded with dlsym

Tags: c++, dlopen

In a C++ project I am loading a `.so` with `dlopen` and `dlsym`. The `.so` is compiled from C source and all functions have C linkages.

The only part I am not able to figure out is how do I cast the resulting pointer to an `extern "C"` function so that the actual call site uses the appropriate linkage.

I know one of the main difference is the name mangling and I don't have to worry about that because I am using the unmangled name to find the function with `dlsym`.

But my understanding is there are other aspects of the linkage which could be a mismatch (I am thinking of exception handling, different ABI?).

I have tried -

```
extern "C" void (*foo) (void) = (void (*) (void)) dlsym(handle, "foo");
```

But the compiler doesn't like `extern "C"` for local variables. What is the right way to call functions loaded with dlsym? Or should I not have to worry about linkages?

Edit: To further clarify the question, I need to compute the function pointer types based on some template parameters which makes this harder and after the discussions in the answers and comments it is currently not possible to do this (the standards are being adjusted to allow this). The current accepted answer correctly answers the question asked.

Comment: As the compiler doesn't let you use this modifier for functors, it is safe to not use this modifier for functors.

Comment: It is obvious, a local variable does not have the external linkage, thus the extern "C" is not applicable to a local variable.

Comment: @273K is it possible that the C and C++ ABIs are different and the compiler needs to know to use the C ABI when calling this function?

Comment: @user253751 Honestly I do not understand your question. ABI is for a linker, not for a compiler. `extern "C"` just directs a compiler how to assign an exported name to an object. Perhaps you confused `extern "C"` and calling convention.

Comment: @273K compilers certainly care about ABIs (calling conventions)

Comment: @273K the compiler has to generate the code for the callsite when this function pointer is called. It would need to know that the function being called uses the C ABI. Without the extern "C" it would follow the C++ ABI. Ofcourse it matters only if the target uses different ABI for C and C++.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond do you have any reference that says it is safe to not use `extern "C"` on local function pointers?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya C and C++ both use cdecl calling conventions. Each of them can be tuned for using different calling conventions only on x86, and variable argument functions are not available in other calling conventions. All calling conventions but cdecl are ignored on x64. `extern "C"` does not affect a calling convention, it is not a part of ABI except naming.

Comment: It is safe not to do something you cannot do. If you should do it, there were a way to do it.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond do you have any reference for that? Also are you sure there is no other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce a **typedef** first:

```
extern "C" typedef void (*verb)();
void f() {
  const auto foo=(verb)dlsym(handle, "foo");
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about the same way. Is it possible to do such a typedef inside a class? Basically I am trying to write a function with templates that accepts a function pointer and returns another function pointer whose type depends on the input function pointer. With variadic templates I am able to construct the return type, but how do I add extern to it?

Comment: Can I wrap the function in a class and have the typedef inside the class? From what I read, the `extern "C"` is ignored for functions inside classes. Would it also be ignored for typedefs inside classes?

Comment: My current signature looks like this - `template <typename FT> auto load(FT f) -> typename type_creator<FT>::type;`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: `extern "C" {…}` applies to function **types** expressed in classes, though not to member functions themselves.  The problem is that, due to some [really bad wording](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1463), it is taken to be forbidden to declare a template inside, which makes it difficult or impossible to *compute* a type with C linkage.

Comment: So is it right to say that the standard does not allow computing `extern "C"` function pointer types? Also thanks for the reference.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: The idea is that the standard is being fixed to allow it.

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I will just use it without the `extern "C"` and hope that the calling conventions are the same for my architecture.